# Update Oracle CLOB with PHP

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I have an Oracle table with 1 field of datatype CLOB.

I want to replace the contents of the CLOB with a long string (over 4,000 characters).

Is OCI8 the easiest way to do this using PHP?

Regular sql would be simply something like this:

Update TableX
Set clobFieldX = 'my very long string'
Where keyField = 'value';

I've been googling for a simple example but can't find one that updates the CLOB with a 'where something = something' clause.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-descriptor.php has an example of an insert statement.  I'll try it in a bit, but it is as simple as changing the insert example to an update example?

Side note:  is OCI the best way to interact with Oracle with PHP?  Is there is a friendlier library/extension?

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  Darn.

Answer (score 1):

```
This worked: function updateClob($groupId,$memberList,$conn) {
$sql = "UPDATE LP_GROUP SET MEMBER_EXPR_XML = EMPTY_CLOB() WHERE GROUP_ID = '$groupId' RETURNING MEMBER_EXPR_XML INTO :lob";
//echo $sql."\n";
$clob = OCINewDescriptor($conn, OCI_D_LOB);
$stmt = OCIParse($conn, $sql);
OCIBindByName($stmt, ':lob', &$clob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);
OCIExecute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT);
if($clob->save($memberList)){
    OCICommit($conn);
    echo $groupId." Updated"."\n";
}else{
    echo $groupId." Problems: Couldn't upload Clob.  This usually means the where condition had no match \n";
}
$clob->free();
OCIFreeStatement($stmt);
```

}